# Batch-Script: Search subfolders, find file, delete all else

Tags: file, batch-file, for-loop, if-statement

I've been trying to figure this out for some time now, and I have been searching the web immensely, but I couldn't find the right answer just yet. 
So here's my problem:

I want to create a batch file, that searches through all subfolders of a certain directory, finds a specific file and then deletes everything but that file in the folder that the searched file was in.

What I came up with so far is this:

```
cmd /k for /f %%a IN ('dir /b /s Neuer') do if not [%%a] == [index.txt] del /q %%a
```

But that deletes just every file in every subfolder - not quite what I want.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Rethink your logic: you are deleted every file that is not `index.txt`; since you are using `dir /B /S`, `%%a` returns full paths, so nothing is ever going to be equal to `index.txt`. Then rmove `cmd /K` as it is useless, and add `"delims="` after `for /F` to not having trouble with paths containing spaces...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @echo off

    setlocal

    if "%~2" == "" (
      echo/Usage: %~nx0 ^<directory^> ^<file^>
      echo/
      echo/%~nx0 will search the given ^<directory^> and its subdirectories
      echo/looking for ^<file^>. If the ^<file^> is found, then all the other
      echo/files and subdirectories in the same directory as ^<file^> will be
      echo/deleted. If more than one ^<file^> is found then this action is
      echo/repeated for all matches. Wildcards are not accepted; ^<file^> can
      echo/be the name of either a file or a directory.
      exit /b
    )

    if not exist "%~1\" (
      echo/%nx0: "%~1" does not exist or is not a directory
      exit /b
    )

    set "TARGETNAME=%~2"

    for /r "%~1" %%t in (*) do call :checkFile "%%~t"
    for /r "%~1" %%t in (.) do call :checkDir "%%~t"

    exit /b

:checkFile

    if not "%~nx1" == "%TARGETNAME%" exit /b
    echo/* Found "%~1"
    echo/  - Deleting files in directory "%~dp1" . . .
    for %%f in ("%~dp1*") do call :delFile "%%f"
    echo/  - Deleting directories in directory "%~dp1" . . .
    for /d %%d in ("%~dp1*") do call :delDir "%%d"
    exit /b

:checkDir

    set "TESTNAME=%~1"
    call :checkFile "%TESTNAME:~0,-2%"
    exit /b

:delFile

    if "%~nx1" == "%TARGETNAME%" exit /b

    echo/    : del "%~1"
    rem        del "%~1"
    exit /b

:delDir

    if "%~nx1" == "%TARGETNAME%" exit /b

    echo/    : rd /q /s "%~1"
    rem        rd /q /s "%~1"
    exit /b
```

Notes:

1. In production one would of course do some error checking.

   - Maybe some files cannot be deleted because they have the readonly attribute, or the user running the script does not have the appropriate privileges, or they are in use, etc.
   - Maybe some directories cannot be deleted, for similar reasons, or because they contain hidden files, or because they contain files which cannot be deleted.
2. The script looks for both *files* and *directories* with the given name; it is easy to see how to limit the search to files only.
3. The script will do its work for *all* files or directories matching the given name.
4. As illustrated here the script does not actually delete anything, it just prints what would be deleted. To make it actually do the deletion just remove the `rem` in front of `del` and `rd`.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly for this kind of issues, the command `forfiles` has been invented:

[ForFiles explanation](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwixsIKniqbcAhWBEVAKHa1JAUUQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fwindows-server%2Fadministration%2Fwindows-commands%2Fforfiles&usg=AOvVaw2uBwoYLQ_HuO1IrCz7LAoa)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about that!